# Can a CSV used in Data Loader have unused fields?

Tags: data-loader, data

We are using the Upsert command in Salesforce Data Loader. If we have a CSV with several columns we do not wish to update (it's a wide CSV), can we still use it and just not map it? Or do all columns in the CSV have to be mapped to be consumed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use every column in the CSV. The data loader will only affect the columns that are explicitly mapped.